# Inconsistent measurments with viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I did some measurements (1,2) with the "sticky" mode in the viewer. Then I did some measurements (3,4) in the "free" mode. These lines have similar length but a totally different size. Would it be possible to configure the viewer that both modes measure same sizes?
[image]
The calibration:

- Unit meter
- Accuracy 0.001
- Browser Chrome 117.0.5938.149